# Vertical scroll is moving when removing one line of text inside the tiptap editor

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, tiptap

As the title says, it's not what I want. The expected result is it should behave like a textarea: when one line of text is removed, the vertical scroll position should not move. I provided a video and reproducible sandbox: [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/tiptap-vue-forked-fyg6jg) so that it's clear.

[image]

```html
<div style="border: 1px solid black; height: 192px; overflow: auto">
  <EditorContent :editor="editor" style="height: 90%" />
</div>
```

I don't know what's going on here. Please help.

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise to show some code _here_.